# What are the minimum and maximum of $x$ and $y$ within the set $ 0 \le x \le 2$, $x - 2 \le y \le x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Given a set, how do I calculate what it's minimum and maximum is for x and y?

$$ 0 \le x \le 2 \ , \ x - 2 \le y \le x$$

I informally look at it and think "if x is 0, then y is at most 0, and least -2. If x is 2, y is at most 2 and at least 0, thus x goes from 0 to 2, and y from -2 to 2"....

But how does one show above "algebraically", i.e. by calculating with the equalities? I just think above is way too informal?

Comment: Hint: use a visual aid!

Comment: Hah, I already did that. I just really want to show it algebraically? There must be a way :O?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum and minimum value for $x$ are clearly $2$ and $0$. There's little way to be more explicit regarding this than the given iniequality $0\le x\le 2$.

By combining the inequalities one finds $y\le x\le2$, hence $y\le 2$, and $y\ge x-2\ge -2$ (where the latter is obtained by adding $-2$ to both sides of $x\ge 0$), so that we conclude that $-2\le y\le 2$. To be on the safe side, it is better to additionally exhibit pairs $(x,y)$ that show that $y$ really attains these (possibly less than perfect) bounds. That's easy, just let $(x,y)=(2,2)$ and $(x,y)=(0,-2)$ and verify that the given iniequalites hold.